# Datalist not showing list of countries

Tags: html

Data list doesn't appear. Tried everything. I know the data list is correct.

```
<input name="country" list="country_name">
<datalist i="country_name">
<option value="Afghanistan">
<option value="Albania">
<option value="Algeria">
<option value="Andorra">
<option value="Armenia">
<option value="Australia">
<option value="Austria">
<option value="Azerbaijan">
<!-- etc. -->
</datalist>
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be id

```
<datalist id= "country_name">
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the `id` of your datalist.

`i="country_name"` should be `id="country_name"`

```html
<input name="country" list="country_name">
<datalist id="country_name">
<option value="Afghanistan">
<option value="Albania">
<option value="Algeria">
<option value="Andorra">
<option value="Armenia">
<option value="Australia">
<option value="Austria">
<option value="Azerbaijan">
<!-- etc. -->
</datalist>
```